# How to solve set of linear differential equation in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a set of linear differential equations and are written in this format
[X']=[Y]-[R]
where
[P][Y]=[Q]
My actual P matrix size is of 20x20 and Q is of 20x1 and Y is of 20x1. I have written this code in Matlab there it was very easy. I'm finding it very difficult to write it in Mathematica.
For example P, Q and R as follows 
[image] 
What is the plot(x1,x2) and plot(t,x1). If you find this example meaningless kindly take your own P, Q and R functions and solve it. Kindly provide the Mathematica code.

Comment: Please show us the text of code, not the screenshot of it.

Comment: So where is the differential equation you are trying to solve? Note, in MA $df(x)/dx$ is written as `D[f[x],x]`. The equal sign in equations is `==`. This `=` is an assignment operator(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).

Comment: Please, look in the Documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) on how the differential equations are written. This  is another Tutorial https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToNumericalDifferentialEquations.html

Comment: You mentioned _"x'" implies derivative with respect to time "t"_, but also introduced notations like **x'**, **dx** and **dy** in your question, what exactly is the ODE system you want to solve? Please show us the equation in traditional math notation.

Comment: Solving this using `NDSolve` should be straightforward, which part are you having difficulty? Have you read the document shown by @yarchik ?

Answer (score 2):

We solve **a system of ODEs**:
$$
p(t)\cdot\dot{\vec{x}}(t)=\vec{q}(t)-p(t)\cdot\vec{r}(t)
$$
with
$$
p(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\sin(t)&\exp(t)\\1&\cos(t)\end{array}\right),
\quad
\vec{x}(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{array}\right),
$$
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\vec{x}(t)+\left(\begin{array}{c}\sin(t)\\\cos(t)\end{array}\right),
\quad
\vec q(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1(t)\sin(t)\\1+x_1(t)x_2(t)\end{array}\right).
$$
where $p(t)$ is a matrix and $\vec{x}(t),\vec{q}(t),\vec{r}(t)$ are time-dependent vectors. Notice, that this form *is equivalent* to the original formulation, but *avoids matrix inversion*.

- A list of *dependent* variables `vx`and a list of
  initial conditions `vx0`.

---

```
vx=Array[x,2];
vx0={0,1};
```

- Build a matrix `p`and two vectors `q` and `r`.

---

```
p={{Sin[t],Exp[t]},{1,Cos[t]}};
q={x[1][t]Sin[t],1+x[2][t]x[1][t]};
r=Through[vx@t]+{Sin[t],Cos[t]};
```

**Notice:**

1. `vx` is equal to `{x[1],x[2]}`,
2. `Through[vx@t]` is equal to `{x[1][t],x[2][t]}`,
3. `Through[vx@0]` is equal to `{x[1][0],x[2][0]}`.

---

- Construct equations `eqs`  and initial conditions `ics`. Notice that `Equal` is just the full form of `==`, a dot `.` means matrix-vector (or matrix-matrix) multiplication, and `D[Through[vx@t],t]` is the time-derivative of the vector of dependent variables, that is $\dot{\vec{x}}(t)=\left\{\dot{x}_1(t),\dot{x}_2(t)\right\}^T$:

---

```
eqs=MapThread[Equal,{p.D[Through[vx@t],t],q-p.r}];
ics=MapThread[Equal,{Through[vx@0],vx0}];
```

- Now solve and plot the first solution `First[sol]`. In fact, there is a unique solution:

---

```
sol=NDSolve[Join[eqs,ics],vx,{t,20}];
Plot[Through[vx@t]/.First[sol],{t,0,20},Evaluated->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to use `MapThread` and `Join`, `NDSolve` can handle nested lists and equations like `{…, …}=={…, …}`, at least since _v9_.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, that is even more terse.